# Hibernate try to to access entity with primary key instead of refercolumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-repositories

I have a entity with a column definition like this

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "issuer_id",referencedColumnName = "ISSUER_ID")
public IssuerEntity getIssuerEntity() {
    return issuerEntity;
}
```

I am using SpringJpaRepository for CRUD operation.

```
SpringJpaRepository.findAll() works fine
```

but when i use `SpringJpaRepository.fineOne(id)` 
hibernate tries to access with primary key of IssuerEntity instead of refer column ISSUER_ID.
Here is the error log

```
2016-05-14 09:56:32,529 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-20) SQL Error: 17026, SQLState: 99999
2016-05-14 09:56:32,529 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-20) Numeric Overflow
2016-05-14 09:56:32,529 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (default task-20) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,542 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) 2016-05-14 09:56:32,540 [default task-20] ERROR com.od.api.aop.CommonExceptionHandlerAdvice - error processing request org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000] 
2016-05-14 09:56:32,542 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,542 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:415) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,542 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:418) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,542 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,543 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy756.findOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.od.provisioning.core.service.ServiceDefinitionServiceImpl.getById(ServiceDefinitionServiceImpl.java:72) ~[classes:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor579.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,544 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy757.getById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.od.provisioning.api.ep.ServiceDefinitionEndPoint.get(ServiceDefinitionEndPoint.java:105) ~[classes:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor578.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,546 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,547 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.od.config.spring.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:57) [classes:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,548 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.od.config.app.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:57) [classes:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.common.filter.CorrelationIdFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdFilter.java:40) [commons-2.1.6.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.common.filter.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:24) [commons-2.1.6.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,551 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-8.2.0.Final.jar!/:8.2.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,552 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,553 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,553 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,553 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,553 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:1.1.0.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1694) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1141) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1074) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor304.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy702.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor304.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,555 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy574.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:235) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor518.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout]  task-20)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,556 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    ... 77 common frames omitted
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.od.configuration.core.entity.IssuerEntity#250000]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,558 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,560 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,560 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,560 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,560 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,560 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,560 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,561 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,561 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,561 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,561 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,561 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar!/:4.3.7.Final]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    ... 101 common frames omitted
2016-05-14 09:56:32,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
2016-05-14 09:56:32,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4170) ~[ojdbc-7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:179) ~[ojdbc-7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getInt(GeneratedStatement.java:217) ~[ojdbc-7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,563 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:573) ~[ojdbc-7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
2016-05-14 09:56:32,563 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:1350) ~[ojdbc-7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```